# How to get the length of EC key in a EC certificate?

Tags: certificate, key

I have a EC certficate(the signature algorithm is ECDSA),I want to know the length of EC key using openssl api.
Now, I can get the EC_KEY structure from the certificate,but I don't know  which elem in EC_KEY is the length of key and how to get it.

The following is the structure of EC_KEY:

```
struct ec_key_st {
    int version;
    EC_GROUP *group;// used to represent the definition of an elliptic curve
    EC_POINT *pub_key;//used to store the points on the elliptic curve
    BIGNUM   *priv_key;
    unsigned int enc_flag;
    point_conversion_form_t conv_form;
    int     references;
    int flags;
    EC_EXTRA_DATA *method_data;
} /* EC_KEY */;
```

Please help!

Answer (score 4):

ECC key size is defined by the size of `EC_GROUP` parameter `p`.  Provided you have your `EC_KEY *` in variable `ec`, you can get to that using

```
int bits = BN_num_bits(ec->group->p);
```

or better from the `EVP_KEY` structure using function

```
int bits = EVP_PKEY_bits(EVP_PKEY *pkey);
```

**Edit 2018**:
With OpenSSL 1.1.0+ opaque structures, we can not access the structure elements directly anymore, but we need to use specific function (not available in older OpenSSL 1.0.x versions):

```
EC_GROUP *g = EC_KEY_get0_group(ec);
int bits = EC_GROUP_order_bits(g);
```

But the most portable way is using the `EC_GROUP_get_degree()`, which is available in all OpenSSL versions (1.0.2 to 1.1.1 for now):

```
EC_GROUP *g = EC_KEY_get0_group(ec);
int bits = EC_GROUP_get_degree(g);
```